# How can I elegantly determine a central interval of a given distance M in an array of length N?

Tags: matlab

I have an array `x=1:N`. I want to visualize the central part of a curve determined by `x`, say only the part `xx=N/2-M/2:N/2+M/2`. I know I can do this if I round everything (N and M can be anything), but this makes a simple indexing operation quite lengthy and unreadable. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Have you found any other method to do this? I'm curious.

Comment: nope, the below solutions are pretty much the shortest I've seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust your thinking, express the size of the interval in terms of its 'radius' (call it `m`) rather than its 'diameter' (`M`) and, voila

```
xx = median(x)-m:median(x)+m
```

That's way more elegant, isn't it !  Since you'll probably want integers everywhere try

```
xx = floor(median(x)-m):ceil(median(x)+m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Rounding is implicitly done by MATLAB on integer types, so you can simply convert `M` and `N` to integers:

```
N = uint32(N);
M = uint32(M);
xx = N/2-M/2:N/2+M/2;
```